# How to detect DOMException (Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node) Using JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, domexception

I am working on a chrome extension that modifies page's HTML using Jquery. This doesn't work on many React sites if it is loaded . Specifically, I observed that the react site will throw this out:

```
react-dom.production.min.js:216 
DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.
    at Eu (https://tbsn.herokuapp.com/static/js/2.802c0af0.chunk.js:2:207399)
    at xs (https://tbsn.herokuapp.com/static/js/2.802c0af0.chunk.js:2:219229)
    at e.unstable_runWithPriority (https://tbsn.herokuapp.com/static/js/2.802c0af0.chunk.js:2:239845)
    at  (https://tbsn.herokuapp.com/static/js/2.802c0af0.chunk.js:2:162204)
    at As (https://tbsn.herokuapp.com/static/js/2.802c0af0.chunk.js:2:217187)
    at ys (https://tbsn.herokuapp.com/static/js/2.802c0af0.chunk.js:2:213273)
    at https://tbsn.herokuapp.com/static/js/2.802c0af0.chunk.js:2:162427
    at e.unstable_runWithPriority (https://tbsn.herokuapp.com/static/js/2.802c0af0.chunk.js:2:239845)
    at  (https://tbsn.herokuapp.com/static/js/2.802c0af0.chunk.js:2:162204)
    at Wi (https://tbsn.herokuapp.com/static/js/2.802c0af0.chunk.js:2:162372)
```

Is it possible to detect this DOMException using JS being thrown out by the react site so I can disable the chrome extension for this site

Here's why I am editing the DOM. Supposing the original html is

```
<h1>Hello World</h1>
```

I need to highlight 'Hello' on the screen, so I replaced the innerHTML of h1 element. The result will look like this

```
 <h1><span>Hello</span> World</h1>
```

This way I can add css styling to the  to highlight the word 'Hello'. I  wonder if there is another way to do this without working with DOM directly

Comment: It's best to fix your code so it doesn't break sites. A common mistake is to replace html instead of working with DOM directly.

Comment: Quick question about working with DOM. For example, if I am trying to change <h1>I need you</h1> to <h1>I <span>need</span> you</h1>, I guess I have to replacing html right? Is there a nother way?

Comment: I need to see your code first. If it replaces `h1` then it's definitely wrong. If it just changes the node's innerHTML then the problem is more complicated but we're not there yet.

Comment: I just added the code to the question. Can't put HTML in the comment. Appreciate it if you could have a look.

Comment: Try creating a new element that's positioned over this one (you can use getBoundingClientRect maybe or just add the element *after* the original one) and hide the old one by adding `hidden` attribute, for example.

Comment: Thank you. Will try this! This way React would track the Dom change even if react program itself didn't do it, but from a web extension?

Comment: The idea is that React won't see this additional node so it won't fail internally.